# Elasticsearch - Provide remote file path for synonym

Tags: java, indexing, elasticsearch, lucene

Is it possible to provide remote file path for synonym.

```
"synonym" : {
                "type" : "synonym",
                "synonyms_path" : "\\\\remote.ip\\home\\...\\synonym.txt"
            }
```

If not possible, could anyone give some idea to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a question of Elasticsearch allowing remote file access, but it's a question of how the remote machine allows external access to its files. Elasticsearch, under the cover, just uses `java.io.File` for loading the files.

For example, if you have a remote file locally mounted in *nix machine using NFS or Samba for Windows then I believe it is possible to specify such paths. And your path will not be `\\IP\whatever\text.txt` but `/[locally_mounted_folder]/whatever/text.txt`. A quick google related to NFS, for example: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/System_Administration_Guide/s1-nfs-mount.html